# How to download a bunch of pdf files linked from an html file?

Tags: javascript

My friend's computer broke and the only thing he can use to view his geometry book is the accessible page: http://www.classzone.com/cz/books/geometry_2007_na/secured/resources/applications/ebook/accessibility/ml_geometry_na/toc.html because he has an iPad that is incapable of viewing flash.

The link to the first page looks like: .....http://www.classzone.com/cz/books/geometry_2007_na/secured/resources/applications/ebook/accessibility/ml_geometry_na/page_1.pdf

Page two: .....blahblah/page_2.pdf all the way up to page_1000.pdf

The problem is there is no "next page" button, so its a hassle to switch pages. Also, it takes an internet connection to do.

How can I download all of these pdf's to a folder so he can see read them on his iPad easier? I would also like to have this option, so I can view my math book offline. I know javascript, and was thinking of a for loop:

```
for(var i=1; i<=500; i++) {
 var link = "http://www.classzone.com/cz/books/geometry_2007_na/secured/resources/applications/ebook/accessibility/ml_geometry_na/page_" + i + ".pdf";
 // how can I download the pdf from variable link 
}
```

Thank you so much! If javascript can't do this, can any other programming language?

Comment: Why don't you just write a bash script and use `wget`? Its a one liner for downloading the pdf file onto your file system.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I dont know bash how would you do this

Answer (score 0):

You could use Perl with `wget` and fetch them pretty quickly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$x = 1;
while ($x < 1001) {
    system ("wget http://www.classzone.com/cz/books/geometry_2007_na/secured/resources/applications/ebook/accessibility/ml_geometry_na/page_$x.pdf");
    $x++;
}
```